# Align protein sequence to Pfam file using HMMER3.0 (hmmalign)

Tags: shell, alignment, bioinformatics

I'm using HMMER 3.0 (hmmalign to be specific) to align the whole proteome of Human to Pfam file. I got the proteome [here](https://www.ensembl.org/info/data/ftp/index.html) and the Pfam file [here](ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Pfam/releases/Pfam31.0/), and downloaded the file `Pfam-A.hmm.gz` with the command:

```
hmmalign -o human.out Pfam-A.hmm Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.pep.all.fa
```

I got the error:

```
Error: HMM file Pfam-A.hmm does not contain just one HMM
```

Comment: hmmalign needs an <hmmfile> with a single profile, Pfam-A.hmm must contain multiple profiles

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using the wrong tool for the job. To cite the HMMER manual, page 70, from their website:

> hmmscan is used to search protein sequences against collections of
> protein profiles.
>
> For each sequence in *seqfile*, use that query sequence to search the target database of profiles in *hmmdb*, and output ranked lists of the profiles with the most significant matches to the sequence

So try to change `hmmalign` to `hmmscan`.

Comment: But why hmmscan, instead of hmmsearch? Since I found an article comparing them [here](https://cryptogenomicon.org/2011/05/27/hmmscan-vs-hmmsearch-speed-the-numerology/) . It seems that they have the same output, but hmmsearch is faster?

Comment: Well i only had a look at `hmmalign` and saw that its not suited for your problem, not at the intricacies of all methods provided by HMMER. From your article it seems `hmmsearch` is the way to go. :)